# Is there a way to automatically restart MySQL, if it takes up too much processing power?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, central-processing-unit, process

Due to some bad scripting on my part, MySQL sometimes goes haywire - taking up a lot of CPU power (load average of more then 20 - I only have 8 cores)! When I restart it is all good again.

So my question is: is there a way to restart MySQL when it takes up more then 400% CPU?

Preferably I would restart only the associated account(s) which cause the problem.

Server: Linux with whm

Comment: Is this really a good idea? Doesn't it run the risk of leaving your DB in an inconsistent state?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the script?

Comment: @user606723 Could be actively writing scripts. I know something like this would be useful when in testing you run `SELECT * FROM mega_table WHERE (complicated logic)` without realizing it and bring the server to its knees for a long time

Comment: Yes, the ability to kill spids is useful.. but in long term we should fix the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Restarting mysql in that case is a bad practice. It results in thrashing your buffers and if your database is large enough - it will take some time to warm up.

I suppose you have some heavy queries that consumes too much cpu.

Use `mysql> show full processlist` to identify long-running queries and try to optimize them: create indices, re-write queries to run faster and do less sorting.

For immediate results you can kill this queries using:

`mysql> kill QUERYIDNUMBER`

To directly answer your questions - you can safely restart it with `service mysql restart`, but this will take long time. Restarting will block all new connections to the database, but it will wait until all running queries finish. You may kill heavy queries to speed up.

Also if you need to speed-up mysql restarting there's a good trick to do it.

First, run `mysql> set global innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;`
then wait until all (or almost all) dirty buffer pages flush to disk, see
`mysqladmin ext -i10 | grep dirty`

When you have output like this:

`| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty    | 12        |`

You can restart your mysql server and it will be much faster:

`service mysql restart`

Answer (score 6):

I can only repeat that it really is a bad idea trying to solve that problem by restarting mysql. You should try to identify and optimize the queries which cause your server to overload.

Two hints which can help you:

1. [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl) will analyze your current configuration and show you where some of the obvious performance killers are.
2. The [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) will log all the queries lasting longer than a configurable time. You can then analyze the individual queries using the `EXPLAIN` SQL command.

Comment: when LA hits that much - pretty all queries will be in slowlog.

Comment: That is surely true, but it doesn't necessarily need to be a single *bad* query which causes the load to go through the roof. The slow query log (while the systems runs normally) will help identifying large tables and tables with badly chosen indexes and thus help to improve the overall performance of the system.

Comment: Sure, slowlog is of much use when you have suboptimally running mysql. But in case of high LA processlist (especially in percona fork) is much more convenient in finding bad queries.

Comment: Yeah that's true.

Answer (score 4):

monit will do that for you:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monit